# How to negate multiple conditions in the Bourne shell

Tags: shell, sh

I have a simple Bourne shell script like this:

```
if ! pwd && ls && mkdir /opt/test/; then
    echo "failure"
else
    echo "success"
fi
```

I want it to report a failure if any of the commands does not exit successfully e.g. if the `mkdir` command fails due to insufficient permissions. Therefore, the negation should cover all three commands.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by executing the commands in a subshell like this:

```
if ! (pwd && ls && mkdir /opt/test/); then
    echo "failure"
else
    echo "success"
fi
```

The exit status of the subshell is returned and tested by the `if` statement.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply reverse the sense of the test:

```
if pwd && ls && mkdir /opt/test/; then
    echo success
else
    echo failure
fi
```

This can be a problem if you don't have any commands to run for the success case, because it's a syntax error to leave out that block. You can use `true` or `:` (an alias for `true`) as a do-nothing command:

```
if [ -d "$directory" ] || mkdir "$directory"; then
    : directory exists
else
    echo could not create "$directory"; exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Good observation. I had thought of the same but it seemed rather inelegant.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want subshell, try `{}`:

```
if ! {pwd && ls && mkdir /opt/test/ ; }; then
    echo "failure"
else
    echo "success"
fi
```

Or, you can send the negate inside each of the sub-commands (De Morgan's Law):

```
if !pwd || !ls || !mkdir /opt/test/; then
    echo "failure"
else
    echo "success"
fi
```

Comment: Both your answers work. However, you need to edit syntax errors in both of them! The first example needs a space between '{' and 'pwd'. The second example needs a space between each '!' and the command following it. Fix these and I will upvote the answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you have too much commands in the if-statement, it will become hard to read.
You can make a function for it:

```
function myInit {
   pwd || return 1
   ls || return 2
   mkdir /opt/test || return 3
   echo "success" || true
}

myInit || echo "failure"
```

When echo "success" fails, the function returns true, to keep close to your solution.

Comment: This answer works but it's a bit over the top for my simple use case.

Comment: True. In your use case I don't see why you want to check the result of the pwd and ls command and maybe ignore an error when /opt/test already exists. In that case you could do `pwd; ls; mkdir /opt/test; if [ ! -d /opt/test ]; ..`. You wrote that you had a script like the example, I thought you simplified the script for SO. Using `set -o errexit` also seems overkill.

Comment: You're right. My example here used basic commands. The real code has commands that do real work. I just used `ls`, `pwd` and `mkdir` as placeholders for generic commands.